# Spring MVC + Hibernate validator : how can I override/internationalize the default error messages?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, bean-validation, hibernate-validator

I'm working on a Spring MVC project in which I'm using Hibernate Validator to validate input fields from a form. As my project is Maven-based, I added this dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator-annotation-processor</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

The form validation process works fine but now, I would like to override or internationalize the default error messages.

For instance, by default, using the @NotEmpty annotation will yield the message "may not be empty". How I can replace this message by my own message? I've tried several solutions:

- defining a Spring bean with id "messageSource" and setting its "basenames" property
- creating ValidationMessages.properties file in the project classpath

But the default messages are still displayed...

Any hint?
Thx in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you can do that. You can load the error message from the properties files. But you need to have the key in a proper format. Like `NotEmpty.ClassName.fieldName=fieldName Can not be empty`.

You just need to specify your exact class name and property name in your properties files. Everything other is looking just perfect in your case.

You can also have a common error message for a particular type of validation annotation for all the fields having that annotation. Like `javax.validation.constraints.NotNull=Notnull erro happened!`

Hope this helps you. Cheers.

Comment: Thanks, your answer helped me find a satisfactory solution: I've just had to add a properties file named "ValidationMessages.properties" to my classpath. Then, I could either add values pointing to each validation annotation (ex: org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotEmpty.message=my message), or define my own key between brackets, and use this key in the properties file.

Comment: @KHY Setting up generic messages for the hiberate validators was exactly what I was after. Also note that you can do `@NotEmpty(message="xyz {use.braces.for.bundle.keys}")` as your inline Java code, and then do `use.braces.for.bundle.keys=Hey guy, remember to use braces!` as a line of your `ValidationMessages.properties` file. This is nice for invalid date formats in my opinion a la `@Pattern(regexp="\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}", message="{Invalid.Date.UseYMDFormat}")`

Comment: This helped me to see all the error messages to overwrite the defaults: http://www.silverbaytech.com/2013/04/16/custom-messages-in-spring-validation/

Comment: Following the answer I first tried the javax.validation.constraints.NotNull message key but it didn't work. I then took the hint from kyiu and use the org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotEmpty.message message key and it worked. I'm not using Spring for now.

Comment: @Stephane It depends on what validation annotation you have marked on your field in pojo. Based on that your key should be in properties file.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit explanation that how you can find the exact property name behind every annotation given or used for validation. See below mentioned steps.

```
@Size(min = 1, max = 50, message = "Email size should be between 1 and 50")
```

Now remove { message = "Email size should be between 1 and 50" } from validation tag.

After doing this your annotation will be like this.

```
@Size(min = 1, max = 50)
```

Now at controller side debug the method which is being called upon when submitting the form. Below is my method which is receiving the request when user hits submit.

```
public static ModelAndView processCustomerLoginRequest(IUserService userService,LoginForm loginForm, 
    HttpServletRequest request, HttpSession session, BindingResult result, String viewType, Map<String, LoginForm> model)
```

Now place a debug point at very first line of the method and debug the argument "result".

```
BindingResult result
```

While dubugging you will find a string like this in codes array.

```
Size.loginForm.loginId
```

Now define this string in your properties file and a message against that string. Compile and execute. That message will be displayed whenever that annotation wouldn't be validated.

```
Size.loginForm.loginId=email shouldn't be empty.
```

Basically spring makes its own string as key to its property file message. In above key

```
Size(@Size) = validation annotation name
loginForm = My Class Name
loginId = Property name in LoginForm class.
```

The Beauty of this method is it also runs fine while you will be using Spring Internationalization. It automatically switches the messages file as language changes.